# Copy .kube config file from master to all nodes using ansible

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I would like to copy the kube admin config file from the Kubernetes master host to the nodes using ansible synchronize but that fails due to a missing python interpreter, but I have already installed docker on all machines without any issue.

See my task

`- name: admin conf file to nodes
      environment:
        ANSIBLE_PYTHON_INTERPRETER: python3
      synchronize:
        src: /home/{{ansible_ssh_user}}/.kube/config
        dest: /home/{{ansible_ssh_user}}
      delegate_to: "{{item}}"
      loop: "{{groups.node}}"`

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 4):

You can use synchronize module only when rsync is enabled either in source server (kube master in your case) or in the kube nodes.

#### Method 1: to push from master, need rsync enabled in master

Synchronize use `push` mode by default

```
- hosts: nodes
  tasks:
    - name: Transfer file from master to nodes
      synchronize:
        src: /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
        dest: $HOME/.kube/config
      delegate_to: "{{ master }}"
```

#### Method 2: to use fetch and copy modules

```
 - hosts: all
   tasks:
     - name: Fetch the file from the master to ansible
       run_once: yes
       fetch: src=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf dest=temp/ flat=yes
       when: "{{ ansible_hostname == 'master' }}"
     - name: Copy the file from the ansible to nodes
       copy: src=temp/admin.conf dest=$HOME/.kube/config
       when: "{{ ansible_hostname != 'master' }}"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Second method works fine, first method I got an error Ansible is unable to find the sshpass file.

Comment: Yes, as I have mentioned you need to enable rsync in the master or configure ssh connection between master and nodes (this is tedious and not required, at least in your case). Kindly accept my answer, if worked.